# Date is displayed as null while parsing in Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I am facing issue while formatting date in Safari Browser. Please find the details below :

```
value = "2018-02-06";
var tempDate = {value: new Date(value.toString().replace('-','/')) };
```

tempDate is being set as null in Safari but not in other browsers like Chrome and IE. Can you please tell me what is the issue here.?

Comment: why you are adding <br /> tag in javascript. any reason?

Comment: I don't think safari supports `“yyyy-mm-dd”` format, try  pasting it separately: `new Date(2018, 01, 06);`, or rearranging to `new Date("02/06/2018");`

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen : Please run this fiddle in Safari. https://jsfiddle.net/or8g7fxx/

Comment: Actually you are making date as : `2018/02-06` which invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing only one `-`not all. Use `replace(/-/g,'/');` to replace all `-`

[Read in docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

> **substr (pattern)** A String that is to be replaced by newSubStr. It is
>   treated as a verbatim string and is not interpreted as a regular
>   expression. Only the first occurrence will be replaced.

```js
var value = "2018-02-06";
value = value.replace(/-/g,'/');
var tempDate = {value: new Date(value) };
console.log(tempDate);
```

Your code replacing only first `-`, check

```js
value = "2018-02-06";
console.log(value.toString().replace('-','/'));
```

`.toString()` it to convert into string. If it is already string no need to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the format of date value to "02-06-2018" format(mm-dd-yyyy).

Comment: The whole point of using yyyy-mm-dd is that it is not locale dependent.